# MySQL Access Denied for User

Tags: mysql

I am logged in to my MySQL RDS instance from the console (using a password) and I am trying to create a new user

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'newuser'@'%';
```

But I keep running into this issue:
`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)`

The user `root` has super user privileges, but for some reason errors out when I try to grant privileges to new users... any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: What does `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'%'` show?

Comment: I figured it out... `root@%` didn't have SUPER privileges and that's ok cause the new user I was creating didn't need all of the privileges anyway... not enough coffee this morning...